How does Android keep track of if an app has been installed before?
I'm trying to find if there's a location within root where your phone keeps a record of what apps have been installed on your phone, like maybe a database. As a secondary question I'm also trying to find for instance where a game would keep local game saves. I did a test where I installed a game that I had played before, so the default local game save is where I left off. Uninstalled it with SD Maid and double checked data/data for the package name and it was deleted. Reinstalled the app and it had retained the last game save, so it obviously knows it had been installed previously. A factory reset clears any record of an app having been installed, since by doing that, your phone is considered a different device. Anyways, after uninstalling again, I tried doing a find / -name *packagename* > sdcard/output.txt and only ended up with 3 results:
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/backup_chunk_listings/
/data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/backup_chunk_listings/

I assume the save game data would be somewhere on /data/ but no idea where. As for a record of what apps the phone has installed, I have no idea where that would be, my only guess was
data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/

Have you considered that the game itself may have restored it's save games from GDrive or a different cloud store. Alternatively Google Backup may have restored the files. Writing an answer TK your question and your post contains multiple questions. It would be easier if you would describe what you want to achieve in the end.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Well the end result/main question would be if there's a physical location, like a database/file, or a folder with subfolders that google "looks up" to determine if an app has been previously installed before, vaguely similar to the registry in Windows.

For instance, if you have a program that is a timed demo, it has to have some record of it being installed, and most, if not all if the time, deleting any registry entries with that program would be as if the program was never installed, allowing you to re-install to reset the timer.

I guess I was using the game save scenario because it seems the data for that could've possibly in the same locatíon as where Google would look and go "ah, this has been installed before"

Also you mentioned how the app might've restored a game save from a cloud. They would only do that if you bind an account of some sort to the game/app right? A 'guest' account would just be a local game save, unless that's more of a windows thing.

I believe it's the Google Play store that keeps track of which device has installed which apps.

Well, if that's the case, wouldn't it be looking up something it left on ur phone to determine that? Cause once you factory reset, as far as google is concerned, it's a new device and no apps have been installed on it, assuming you didnt have ur apps backed up and auto installed after the reset.

I guess it maybe would've helped narrow that down if I tested with apk's that weren't downloaded from google play and install/un install them to see if they recognize themselves as having been installed previously
